# Group argparse arguments into (sub-) dictionaries

Tags: python, argparse

To parse the parameters for my program, I store default values in a `config.json` file but also allow to overwrite the defaults using command line arguments like so:

`config.json`:

```
{
   "foo_a": 0,
   "foo_b": 1
}
```

`main.py`:

```py
import argparse
import json

def parse_shell_args(args):
    parser = ArgumentParser(description="My program")
    parser.add_argument("--foo_a", type=int, default=argparse.SUPPRESS, help="Foo a")
    parser.add_argument("--foo_b", type=int, default=argparse.SUPPRESS, help="Foo b")

    return vars(parser.parse_args(args))

# Parse shell arguments as dictionary
user_config = parse_shell_args(sys.argv[1:])

# Load default parameter configuration from file
with open("config.json") as config_json_file:
    cfg = json.load(config_json_file)

# Overwrite default parameters with user configuration where specified
cfg.update(user_config)
```

For my purpose it would be great to be able to structure the `config.json` into groups like so:

`config.json`:

```
{
   "foo": {
       "a": 0,
       "b": 1,
   }
}
```

I am puzzled how to properly implement this using argparse. Is there an elegant way of parsing groups of arguments into (sub-) dictionaries?

Comment: Nothing built into `argparse`.  There's been a question or two about grouping the arguments from `subparsers`, but the code to do that either operates after parsing or uses some new Action or Namespace classes.

Comment: Okay that is a pity. The added overhead might not be worth it in my case then. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can flatten `cfg`:

```
cfg = {k1 + '_' + k2: v for k1, cfg2 in cfg.items() for k2, v in cfg2.items()}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggested workaround, I might do something along these lines for now.